# How to escape | for RAILS fields_for in ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, erb, simple-form, fields-for

In our `rails 3.2` app, our view code (in simple_form) is stored in `@erb_code` and render it with inline as:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>

    <%= render inline: ERB.new(@erb_code).result(binding) %>

<% end %>
```

`@erb_code` is a string which stores the view code. There is a `fields_for` block in @erb_code which causes error. Here is the fields_for block:

```
  .........
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :contract do |builder| %>
      <%= render('contract', :f => builder)%>
    <% end %>
  ........
```

Here is the error:

```
(erb):17: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...ds_for :contract do |builder| ).to_s); _erbout.concat "     ...
...                               ^
(erb):21: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
...ut.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
...
```

`)` and `.to_s` were added after |builder| when rendering and those cause the error. Is it escape issue? If it is, how to escape `|builder|` and/or any other in `ERB.new()`?

Comment: Try without the `render inline:` part (just calling `<%= ERB.new(@erb_code).result(binding) %>`)

Comment: Without render inline:, the error is the same.

Comment: tried h before @erb_code. Just plain source code gets displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>

    <%= render inline: @erb_code, locals: {f: f} %>

<% end %>
```

i.e., without using ERB.new. Add more locals as the need be.

In past I have used render inline for similar purposes in Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: This solution works. It requires no change of the view code and is especially helpful if there are quite a few fields_for blocks on the form. Thank you.